# PHP Download Page

Tags: php

How do these PHP download pages (e.g. somesite.com/download.php?id=somefile) often found work?

I originally thought of a page that does the counter stuff, and then simply redirects the user to the files URL (which seems to be the only answer given elsewhere, however I don't see how this provides all the functionality), however among other things, this wouldn’t prevent direct linking, and doesn’t allow me to password protect some files. Some sites even seem to implement download speed limiting (based on user account), queue users, etc.

Comment: Honestly I don't understand the question. Can you explain better?

Comment: This question does not appear to be well researched, and the lack of commentary or meaningful followup questions by the asker on many of the proposed answers seems to suggest that he/she is not genuinely interested in learning how "downloads" mechanisms work for HTTP clients. Hence -1.

Comment: @Fire Lancer: I see you have added some more comments. I'll reverse my downvote on your question if you edit it to provide an example of the direct linking that you don't like, and some more details about the password protection that you want (and why "hardcoded" .htaccess files won't work for you).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, these don't redirect to the file's URL. Instead, they use [`readfile()`](http://php.net/readfile) to directly output the URL from wherever it's being stored (usually, somewhere outside the web root). Solves the direct link, password protection, queuing, etc. issues. Speed limiting would need to be on the web server end.

Comment: Ah ok I see, didnt think of making the script itself serve the file rather than the webserver doing its own thing (was kind of looking for a "tell apache to allow this client access to this file" function). I guess thats why resuming a partial download on many pages doesnt work? Any way around that issue since some of my files are pretty big and both me and I expect the user doesnt want the whole thing sent again cause the connection dropped at 99% :)

Comment: Also does readfile work fairly optimally compared to the webserver itself? I'm highly CPU and RAM limited on my server.

Comment: You'll be tying up an Apache worker, which sounds like it'd be an issue. A potentially good alternative for you would be to host the downloads on Amazon S3 and use their expiring signed URLs. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6540925/amazon-s3-signed-url-in-php has a PHP example.

Comment: @FireLancer: readfile() isn't at all '''optimal''' compared to "static file" serving from the webserver itself (and neither would be any solution which requires a server side script to generate the output dynamically). But you essentially ruled that out in your question by indicating that you don't want "direct linking" - which begs the question "why not?". Note that you *can* password protect "static" files via .htaccess (e.g. by keeping all files which are password protected in a directory with an .htaccess file). And yet many websites *do* serve static content via CGI or mod_php scripts.

Comment: Well I'm aware of the regular password protect file with htaccess, but that gives that standard popup, not tying into PHP login systems and its user database?

Comment: If I can make PHP do the authorisation, and then let IIS/Apache handle the download itself in a portable manner, thats really what I was after

Comment: The "standard popup" (username + password dialog) is what most web browsers produce when they get back an HTTP 401 response (whether generated directly by the webserver or by a PHP script). But if you want to use a relational DB to manage auth & access then yes, you probably want to generate/render your web pages dynamically - and maybe you also want a login/logout workflow for your users?

Comment: For the record, it is *possible* to use a relational DB to control access to certain directories of static content, using [mod_auth_mysql](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialApacheAddingLoginSiteProtection.html#MYSQL), and without rendering the file contents with a PHP script.

Answer (score 1):

Most often it is done by using php function `readfile`:

```
if(is_allowed_to_download()){
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".basename( $file ));
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Length: ". filesize( $file ) );
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

    @readfile($file);
    exit;
}
```

Less often server specific solutions is used - sending header `X-SendFile: file-location.exe` for lighttpd and apache with mod_xsendfile (nginx also have some equivalent). These are slight better, because http servers are optimized to serve content and allow for advanced usage like `Range` headers (for download accelerators).

Answer (score 0):

They just trace many things about you - cookies, IP address, refferer link, browser name.

Comment: To be consistent in my tone I guess I should write: ... another *incredibly insightful* downvote from some brave, articulate SO user... And since you obviously completely missed the point of Peter Szymkowski's comment, he's explaining to you that CGI/mod_php scripts can collect (and log) information about the HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a PHP-specific issue. In order to make the web browser "download" (whether it be the contents of a static file or the body of a dynamically generated report), set the [Content-Disposition header in the HTTP response](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields). PHP allows you to set the HTTP headers using the [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function, so your PHP script should do this before streaming the file contents back to the HTTP client.

Comment: Downvote without comment = [weaksauce](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=weaksauce).

Answer (score 0):

If you precede your DownloadFile() function with some security verification you can easily protect the file, either via using the user_session or sending the password as part of the query.

Comment: And DownloadFile is? A redirect to another file doesnt work since people can direct link the real file

Comment: @FireLancer: atbyrd didn't say to redirect - that's appears to be your own idea (which you again don't like for your own reasons). Did you downvote this one (for no apparent reason)?